# Class based default value for field in Django model inheritance hierarchy

Tags: django, dynamic, model, default, field

How can one accomplish class-based default value in following scheme? I mean, I would like to inherited classes set default value for "number" differently:

```
class OrderDocumentBase(PdfPrintable):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=self.create_number())

    @classmethod
    def create_number(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Invoice(OrderDocumentBase):
    @classmethod
    def create_number(cls):
        return 1

class CreditAdvice(OrderDocumentBase):
    @classmethod
    def create_number(cls):
        return 2
```

I have looked at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573834/django-fields-default-value-from-self-models-instances), but it doesn't address the same problem. The only thing I thought would work was overloading `OrderDocumentBase`'s `__init__` method like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Overload __init__ to enable dynamic set of default to number
    """
    super(OrderDocumentBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    number_field = filter(lambda x: x.name == 'number', self._meta.fields)[0]
    number = self.__class__.create_number()
    number_field.default = number
```

This works, but only partially and behaves quite wierdly. In admin interface, I can see the default being set only after second or latter page refresh. On first try, `None` is being set :(

Second possibility is redefinition of number field in each class, but that doesn't seem too much pretty. Is there any other way?

Can someone help?

Comment: Won't this give you a syntax error `number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=self.create_number())`? There is no `self` in this context.

Comment: Yes, it does - I just wanted to show someting similar to the solution I need to achieve. Sorry for misleading snipped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does feel nicer to do this via default=, but anything you use there doesn't have a way to get at your class or specific model. To have it show up properly in places like the admin, you could set it in **init**() instead of save().

```
class OrderDocumentBase(PdfPrintable):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderDocumentBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk and not self.number:
            self.number = self.DEFAULT_NUMBER

class Invoice(OrderDocumentBase):
    DEFAULT_NUMBER = 2

class CreditAdvice(OrderDocumentBase):
    DEFAULT_NUMBER = 3
```

Comment: Does it really help with admin? My admin panel shows --- as an initial value with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here. First, the `self.method` is not going to work. There is no `self` in the context of the body of the class, which is where you are declaring the `PositiveIntegerField`.

Second, passing a callable will not work as the callable gets bound at compile time and does not change at runtime. So if you define say,

```
class OrderDocumentBase(PdfPrintable):
    create_number = lambda: return 0
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=create_number)

class Invoice(OrderDocumentBase):
    create_number = lambda: return 1
```

All `Invoice` instances will still get `0` as default value.

One way I can think of to tackle this is to override the `save()` method. You can check if the `number` has not been supplied and set it to a default before saving.

```
class OrderDocumentBase(PdfPrintable):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.number:
            self.number = self.DEFAULT
        super(OrderDocumentBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Invoice(OrderDocumentBase):
    DEFAULT = 2

class CreditAdvice(OrderDocumentBase):
    DEFAULT = 3
```

I tested the above with a small change (made `OrderDocumentBase` abstract as I did not have `PdfPrintable`) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Well, I know that the snipped I used does not work, I just wanted to show the way I wish it would work :)

The problem with your solution is that the default value will not be visible in Django admin when creating new object, which is necessary functionality I need. Seems like the only solution is redefinition in each child model.