# Set default value of a field using classmethod in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've found many similar posts on the web about this topic but no one state clearly which is the problem.

**Code**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def get_next_item_number(cls):
        return cls.objects.count() + 1

    number = models.IntegerField(default=get_next_item_number)
```

**Problem**

When I access Django admin panel the text field related to 'number' field contains

```
<classmethod object at 0x7fab049d7c50>
```

So I tried to change the code above

```
class Item(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def get_next_item_number(cls):
        return cls.objects.count() + 1

    number = models.IntegerField(default=get_next_item_number())
```

but when I run django server I get:

```
number = models.IntegerField(default=get_next_item_number())
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

I know all this could be prevented by declaring get_next_item_number() as an external function but this solution is not elegant to me because get_next_item_number() refer only to Item class.

Is there a solution I'm missing?

Comment: have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786987/class-based-default-value-for-field-in-django-model-inheritance-hierarchy

Comment: Those solutions do not provide a default value when I build the ModelForm associated to Item model. I'd rather use an external function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this solution:

**Code**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def get_next_item_number():
        return Item.objects.count() + 1

    number = models.IntegerField(default=get_next_item_number.__func__)
```

I'm not completely aware of the possible consequences, but it works.

Comment: staticmethod and classmethod are not the same thing in python. A staticmethod is not aware about the class at all, so you will not get the class as an argument. In the op's case it might do the job, though

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite `__init__` method of your `Item` class and assing the default value there, have a look to this code:

```
from django.db import models
class Item(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    @classmethod
    def get_next_item_number(cls):
        return cls.objects.count() + 1
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Item, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk and not self.number:
            self.number = Item.get_next_item_number()
```

And here's the flow output

```
>>> from your_app import models
>>> models.Item().save()
>>> models.Item().number
>>> 2
>>> models.Item().save()
>>> models.Item().number
>>> 3
>>> models.Item.objects.filter(id=1)[0].number #number only get its value from classmethod on new items
>>> 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't show the default number value in ModelForm linked to Item model. E.g., in admin panel when I add a new Item the input text of the number field is empty. Isn't really there a way to pass a classmethod to 'default' keyword inside field definition?