# django: how to use a parent's attribute for a field's default

Tags: python, django, model

I would like to set the default category to be whatever the parent's category is set to.

Here's the basic object model right now:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="variants")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', default=get_parent_category)
```

But I don't know how to go about getting the parent's category (what would that method look like?).  Is there a better way to go about it?

(question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573834/django-fields-default-value-from-self-models-instances))

Comment: I would try to set a `getter` method on your Product Class, then call that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the save method.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,related_name="variants")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.parent and not self.pk and not self.category:
        self.category = self.parent.category  # Could use setattr getattr too but this is easier to read imo
    return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If not self.pk is used so that this only happens before the model is committed to the database.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution.  Marking as solved.  (and just so that it is fully correct, maybe you can edit the line below the 'if' statement to be self.parent.category).  Thanks!!!